# java.lang.IllegalStateException: No value for key [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl] with AOP

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, aop

I'm having an error each time I update an entity using Hibernate.
Here's my story:

I have a service with an annotation @Transactional and is calling a DAO.update method.

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class FooServiceImpl implements FooService {
    @Inject
    private FooDAO fooDAO;

    @Override
    public Foo update(Foo foo) {
       return fooDAO.update(foo);
    }

    @Override
    public Foo find(int fooId) {
       return fooDAO.findById(fooId);
    }
}
```

I have an AOP which catch the DAO.update in order to make some operations.

```
@Aspect
@Order(2)
@Component
public class FooTackerAspect {
   @Inject
   private FooService fooService;

   @Inject
   private SessionFactoryManager sessionFactoryManager;

   @Pointcut("execution(* com.foo.bar.FooService.update(..))")
   public void methodToTrack() {}

   @Around("methodToTrack")
   public Object track(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
      int fooId = fetchIdFromJoinPoint(joinPoint);
      Foo foo = fooService.find(fooId);

      // Do some operations

      // I close the session in order to avoid the exception
      // org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with
      // the same identifier value was already associated with the session
      sessionFactoryManager.getSessionFactory(DataSource.FOO)
          .getCurrentSession().close();

      Object retVal = joinPoint.proceed();
      return retVal;
   }
}
```

However, after updating the entity (fooDAO.update(foo)), I get the following error:

```
2056953 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] ERROR o.s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationUtils - TransactionSynchronization.beforeCompletion threw exception 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No value for key [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl@762d6271] bound to thread [http-bio-8080-exec-4]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager.unbindResource(TransactionSynchronizationManager.java:209) ~[spring-tx-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionSynchronization.beforeCompletion(SpringSessionSynchronization.java:193) ~[spring-orm-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.triggerBeforeCompletion(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:106) ~[spring-tx-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerBeforeCompletion(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:938) [spring-tx-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:739) [spring-tx-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:724) [spring-tx-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:475) [spring-tx-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:270) [spring-tx-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94) [spring-tx-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) [spring-aop-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204) [spring-aop-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy112.update(Unknown Source) [$Proxy112.class:na]
```

This error is not blocking (the update still goes through). But I want to correct this error.
Do you have any idea how I can do that?

I think the error comes from the fact I closed the session. But I have to close it in order to update the entity.

Comment: It does not sound healthy to close the session first and to call `FooServiceImpl.update()` afterwards, because this is exactly what `proceed()` does. I recommend you to fix your advice code. Maybe the other exception you want to avoid by closing the session is caused by what you do in your code not disclosed to us, but replaced by comment "do some operations".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @kriegaex said, the problem comes from the fact I'm using the same session to do the **find** and **update** operations.

Given that information, I use this following workaround (which works): I use two separate sessions, one for **find** and the other for **update**.

```
@Repository
public class FooDAOImpl implements FooDAO {
    private FooHibernateDaoSupport hibernateDaoSupport;

    public FooDAOImpl() {
        // Init DaoSupport
    }

    @Override
    public Foo findById(final Serializable fooId) {
        StatelessSession session = hibernateDaoSupport.getSessionFactory().openStatelessSession();
        Foo foo = (Foo) session.get(Foo.class, fooId);
        session.close;
        return foo;
    }

    @Override
    public Foo update(Foo foo) {
        getHibernateTemplate().update(entity);
        return entity;
    }
}
```

With this solution, there is no need to close the session in my advice code anymore.

NB: I'm opening a stateless session because in my project **FooService.update** also calls **FooService.find** in order to set some attributes, so I do not want to have the modifications in my advice code.